# application access to varrying databases

Tags: java, mysql, database

I am working on a project and was wondering what the best practice for the following scenario would be?

I am developing an application that needs to have user access control. When the user launches the application they will be prompted for username and password. The application is designed such that users will be connecting to different databases depending on what school they are from. So, each school is going to have a different database address. So, would i ask the user for the database url at the login prompt too?

Also, how do i re-strict access to the database to only allowing that application access to the database? For instance, you can't launch a different application and try to connect to that database with the same username and password, because it is not the correct application?

Thanks, if you need me to explain anything further, please let me know.

More Detail:

The list of schools would not be set at compile time. Schools would select to use the application and then set up a database for the use of the software and then their students would use the application. So, there would not be an initial list of schools. What would be your suggestion to solve that problem?

Each school host's their own server.

Comment: Are you sure you want a whole different *database* rather than a different *table* for each school? That seems kind of unwieldy to me, but you might have your reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to do a different database per school, or even a different table for that matter.

You can just use a tables like

```
school  -- all schools with data belonging to that school.
------------
id integer primary key auto_increment
name varchar(255)
unique index idx_school (name)

user -- all users from all schools in one table.
--------
id integer primary key auto_increment
username varchar(255)
passhash varchar(200)  -- hashed and salted password
salt varchar(10)       -- salt used, not encrypted, but different per user.
school_id integer not null foreign key references school(id)
unique index idx_user (username, school_id)
```

Select a user using:

```
SELECT u.id FROM user u
INNER JOIN school s ON (s.id = u.school_id)
WHERE s.name = :schoolname
  AND u.name = :username
  AND u.passhash = SHA2(CONCAT(salt,:password),512)
```

The `:....` are your parameters.

Comment: The list of schools would not be set at compile time. Schools would select to use the application and then set up a database for the use of the software and then their students would use the application. So, there would not be an initial list of schools. What would be your suggestion to solve that problem?

Comment: You add schools as and when needed, that's why there's a list of schools. Very simple and very flexible, and much easier than adding a new database every time, and much safer as well.

Comment: Yes but each school has to host their own server. This way their information is kept private to them and only them. I will add that to the post, maybe that wasn't clear.

Comment: I think what i am going to do, is have a properties file associated with the application. The admin of the school would then change the default DB value in the properties file to the DB address and then each user would download the application from their school's website. The application they download would have that property file and it would be specific to their school. How does that sound?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of asking the users to select or enter their corresponding database address, you can use the password they will be using for authentication and make  a user using the same password on the corresponding school database with limited privileges (for e.g. Update,Insert etc. only not giving Drop or delete). So depending on the school selected, the corresponding database url (hard-coded or loaded from a configuration file) will be selected and the password entered will be used for connection, if its correct then the connection to database will happen successfully.

Although this is not solving the second problem of other applications accessing the database with same credentials. Will update the answer if I think about it.